# Fortran: Allocating memory from file read

Tags: memory-management, file-io, input, fortran, subroutine

I try to read a lot of data from a file. The structure of the file is consistent, but the number of times it repeats is not. The first line in input file tells how many times the file repeats. I would like to allocate many vectors with the same length as input file repeats.

Is there a elegant way to solve this, without allocating every single variable? My current subroutine does not work (I am a Fortran Novice).

```
subroutine geometry(N, Aw, Vp, Vtot,Ds, Spos, DIR)
implicit none

  integer, intent(out) :: N
  real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out):: Aw, Vp, Vtot, Ym, Zm, Zt, Ds
  real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: Spos
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: Ns, DIR
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: Hp
  real, parameter :: pi = 4.0*atan(1.0) 
  real :: Vs, Ds, Ns
  integer :: i

  open(unit = 11, file = "semisub.dat")
  read(11,*) N

  allocate(Aw(N))
  allocate(Vp(N))
  allocate(Vtot(N))
  allocate(Ym(N))
  allocate(Zm(N))
  allocate(Zt(N))
  allocate(Ds(N))
  allocate(Spos(N,4))
  allocate(Ns(N))
  allocate(DIR(N))
  allocate(Hp(N))

  do i = 1,N
     read(11,*) Bp, Hp, Lp, Ym(i), Zm(i), DIR(i)
     read(11,*) Ns(i), Ds(i)
     read(11,*) Spos(i,1:Ns(i))
  end do

Aw(:) = 2 * Ds(:) * Ns(:)   
Vp(:) = 2 * Lp(:) * Bp(:) * Hp(:)   
Vs(:) = 2 * Ns(:) * pi * (Ds/2)**2 * (-Zt(:))


 Vtot(:) = Vp(:) + Vs(:)


end subroutine geometry
```

Error log:

```
geometry.f03:7.54:

  integer, dimension(:),allocatable, intent(out) :: Ns, DIR
                                                      1
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
geometry.f03:5.65:

  real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out):: Aw, Vp, Vtot, Ym, Zm, Zt, Ds
                                                                 1
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
geometry.f03:5.69:

  real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out):: Aw, Vp, Vtot, Ym, Zm, Zt, Ds
                                                                     1
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
geometry.f03:5.73:

  real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out):: Aw, Vp, Vtot, Ym, Zm, Zt, Ds
                                                                         1
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
geometry.f03:23.15:

  allocate(Spos(N,4))
               1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (2/1)
geometry.f03:32.20:

     read(11,*) Spos(i,1:Ns(i))
                    1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (2/1)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I wonder if there is a elegant way of solving the problem. My code would not compile. I think it does not accept beeing allocated by using N. Errorcode: Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
geometry.f03:5.52:

Comment: Show full error message, what is at (1)?

Comment: real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out):: Aw, Vp, Vtot, Ym, Zm, Zt, Ds
                                                                   1
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable

Comment: Insert the complete error message in the question and to that always in your future posts.

Comment: Updated first post with whole errorlog.

Comment: Ok, the solution is in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im not able to upvote, but I did aprove solution. This fixed my subroutine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate every array you are filling when reading before. Your approach is OK, with some mistakes not affecting the logic.

The only other option would be to use reallocation by assignment:

```
do...
...
  read(11,*) Ns_tmp, Ds_tmp
  Ns = [Ns, Ns_tmp]
  Ds = [Ds, Ds_tmp]
...
end do...
```

but I wouldn't do that if you know the number of the sections at the start of the file. It is slower and too much complicated.

---

Your error is, that the argument list `(N, Aw, Vp, Vtot,Ds, Spos, DIR)`

is not consistent with your declarations of dummy-arguments:

```
  integer, intent(out) :: N
  real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out):: Aw, Vp, Vtot, Ym, Zm, Zt, Ds
  real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: Spos
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: Ns, DIR
```

Just sort that out and it should work. Just add all arguments in the argument list and do not use `intent` for non-arguments.

The other error is that you declared `Spos` as on-dimensional and you are using it as 2 dimensional.

Comment: By before, you mean allocate in main program? My plan was to keep this subroutine as a single object-code. Could that be causing problems?

Comment: If you have the number of the sections at the start of the file, just use it and allocate, more or less as you do it.