# How to input a string value of unknown length from console in Fortran?

Tags: string, fortran, user-input

I want to take a string input and display it in Fortran.
I tried doing this

```
program name
    implicit none
    
    character(:), allocatable :: a
    print *, "Enter a name: "
    read(*,*) a
    print *, "Hello, ", a, "!"

end program name
```

But I get an error

```
Enter a name: 
Coder

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x657724a3
#1  0x656ff44d
#2  0x4010d0
```

How do i solve it?
I just want to take someone's name and display it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fortran: Allocating memory from file read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373052/fortran-allocating-memory-from-file-read)

Comment: @veryreverie, this is for reading from console not from file!

Comment: It's the same problem though: you haven't allocated `a` before reading.

Comment: @veryreverie, a code solution would be helpful as im new